# MomentJS use BC for negative years

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am very happy with Moment.js.

I am using `date.format( 'll' );` to print a date like this `Jan. 1. 2191`

What I would like to change is that when a year is negative it should use `BC` instead of showing a negative year `Jan. 1. -2191`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Would be more helpful if you could show an attempt and any issues that you have in doing so

Comment: Were you able to insert a negative year to moment (or date object)? When I try it, it automatically converts the year to a positive value where moment("-1995/12/05", "YYYY/MM/dd") == moment("1995/12/05", "YYYY/MM/dd")

Comment: You have to provide leading zeros.